# How to assert/locate a button that has a selector like disabled

Tags: css

I could need some help in order to access properties on a button (as an example)
I'm writing end-to-end tests using Nightwatch, where we have to locale elements in order to assert different things.

I have the following picture:

[image]

Here you see that the button as a class (preferred-action) and id (SubmitContinue) and a disabled property.

I know how to locale classes, like: **.classname** or id's like **#idname**

How do I then assert that this button has a disabled property?

Answer (score 1):

With attribute selector `[attr=value]`

```css
button[disabled="disabled"] {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button class="random" id="random" disabled="disabled">Button</button>
```

If you want to select buttons with attribute `disabled` no matter what the value is you can use `[attr]` selector

```css
button[disabled] {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button class="random" id="random" disabled="disabled">Button</button>
<button class="random" id="random" disabled="enabled">Button</button>
```

Comment: but how if there is multiple buttons on the page?, then this code will take the first it sees?

Comment: No it will select all buttons with `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: the style will be applied to all elements matching this selector

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about selectors, like I need to check that this specific button has a property of disabled?

Comment: If you only want to check for property you can use `button[disabled]` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1172/

Comment: @Mandersen ```button[disabled]```will match all the buttons with that property, no matter what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jquery:

```
$('#SubmitContinue').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Don't have access to jquery, so not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, but in addition to Nenad Vracar's answer:

Since the disabled attribute is a boolean attribute (see [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute)), presence means true and absence means false (i.e. `disabled`, `disabled="disabled"` and even `disabled="false"` are all the same). So the `button[disabled]` selector should always be good.